# How to change the value of observable in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a variable declared `$groups: Observable<any>;`

adding values to that observale like this.

```
this.$groups = Observable.from([[], ...this.groups])
                .mergeMap(x => Observable.timer(timer++ * 1000).map(y => x))
                .scan((acc, curr, seed) => {
                    acc.push(curr);
                    return acc;
                });
```

Is there any way I can directly assign the value to this variable and not using mergemap and scan. Tried to do with subject but not possible with that too. let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, personnally I use

```
let obs$ = Observable.of(myValue);
```

And it works pretty well.